# Solutions to a linear equation over a subfield of a finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I know that if we have a line defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p=K$ then this line has p+1 solutions in $P^2(K)$, $p^2+1$ in $P^2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ and so on. But what about the opposite? If the line is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ how many solutions does it have in $P^2(K)$?

Comment: Let $u\in\mathbb F_{p^2}$ be such that $u^2+u+1=0$. Then, the line $x+uy=0$, defined over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$, has no solutions in $\mathbb P^2(K)$. On the other hand, the line $x=0$ has $p+1$ solutions in $\mathbb P^2(K)$.

Comment: What about the lines defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\setminus \mathbb{F}_p$? Do all of this lines have no solution over K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line in $P^2$ is defined by an equation $ax+by+cz=0$ where $a,b,c$ are not all $0$.  The set of solutions $(x,y,z)\in K^3$ to such an equation is just a vector subspace of $K^3$ whose dimension is $3-d$ where $d$ is the dimension of the span of $\{a,b,c\}$ as a vector space over $K$.  The solutions in $P^2(K)$ are the just the projectivization of this vector subspace, which has $\frac{p^{3-d}-1}{p-1}$ elements.  In the case where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, this $d$ can only be $1$ or $2$.  In the case $d=1$, you get $p+1$ elements in $P^2(K)$ and the line is actually defined over $K$ (any two of $a,b,c$ are linearly dependent over $K$, so you can rescale to make one of them $1$ and then the rest are also in $K$).  In the case $d=2$, you get just $1$ element on $P^2(K)$.

Comment: It seems very nice but I'm not sure if I totally get it:
-where does the formula $\frac{p^{3-d}-1}{p-1}$ come from?
-why can d only be 1 or 2?
-isn't the 1 element of the case d=2 just (0,0,0) that we don't like?

Comment: A vector space over $K$ of dimension $n$ has $p^n$ elements.  To projectivize it, you remove the origin to get $p^n-1$ elements, then mod out the action of $K^\times$ to get $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$ elements.

Comment: $d$ can only be $1$ or $2$ since it is the dimension of a nonzero $K$-linear subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, which itself is a $K$-vector space of dimension $2$.

Comment: Last question, how does this behave with intermediate fields? for example if the line is over $\mathbb{F}_{p^8}$  how many solutions are there over $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}$ for i=4,2,1?

Comment: It works pretty much the same; just replace $p$ with the size of the smaller field.  (And $d$ may be $3$ if the dimension of the larger field over the smaller field is greater than $2$.)

Comment: Ok. very nice indeed